# Check radio button | jQuery

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I'm stuck, I'm not sure which way I should use to solve this. I have four radio buttons

```
<label class="btn btn-default active">
    <input type="radio" name="_hsync_rasa" id="0" autocomplete="off" checked> Bijelac
</label>
<label class="btn btn-default">
    <input type="radio" name="_hsync_rasa" id="1" autocomplete="off"> Crnac
</label>
<label class="btn btn-default">
    <input type="radio" name="_hsync_rasa" id="2" autocomplete="off"> Hispanac
</label>
<label class="btn btn-default">
    <input type="radio" name="_hsync_rasa" id="3" autocomplete="off"> Azijac
</label>
```

So, my question is how to uncheck and check other button? I did code but it doesn't work. Only problem is because I use 0 and 1 for sex(male-female), input name is different, it's not _hsync_rasa.

```
function _hsync_prilagodi_rasu(_trenutna, _nova)
{
    $("input[name=_hsync_rasa]:radio:id:#"+ _nova +"").attr('checked', 'checked');
}
```

I added two params _trenutna(it means current) and _nova(it means new) becase I'm not sure will current radio button uncheck when jQuery check new radio button.

Comment: maybe `s/id/value/g`

Comment: What? I don't understand what You mean.

Comment: How about unchecking all elements with the same name then checking the one you want?

Comment: But I don't Know how to uncheck it, how to get that element? Problem is I use same ID for sex(0 and 1). I don't Know how to select input with name _hsync_rasa and (un)check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to uncheck the other radiobutton first. There can only be one radiobutton (with the same name of course) be checked. Checking another one will automatically uncheck the previous one.

So this is enough

```
  $('[name=_hsync_rasa]#3').prop('checked', true);
```

Or to clear all selected items

```
  $('[name=_hsync_rasa]').prop('checked', false);
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/petervanderwal/3vnvtv6m/3/)

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work properly. It does

    checked="checked"

Comment: @SilvioCro fixed, .attr() is old school, .prop() works better

Comment: Nope, now it just uncheck, it won't check other. Here's a code

    `
    var _hsync_nova_rasa = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3); // RANDOM NUMBER BETWEEN 0 AND 3
$('[name=_hsync_rasa]#'+ _hsync_nova_rasa +'').prop('checked', true);`

Comment: Verify the value of `_hsync_nova_rasa`, as far as I can check this code works -- https://jsfiddle.net/petervanderwal/3vnvtv6m/4/

Comment: Value can't be random, in this case?

Comment: Still working: https://jsfiddle.net/petervanderwal/3vnvtv6m/5/ -- I'm willing to help, but please provide an example (jsfiddle) of code where you encounter the error.

Comment: Here's fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/8ed5j97a/
When user click on muško or žensko(male and female on English), jQuery get random value(0 - 3) and select/check one of four radio buttons up.
Thanks!

Comment: Your whole on-change isn't called. A) Include the jquery-library in your `<head>` (before your own script) if you didn't already do that (https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery) b) make sure your code is runned afther the dom is ready, for example by wrapping it in `$(function() { --your code--  });`

Comment: It's included on bottom

    ` <!-- OVO UVIJEK DRŽI NA DNU - BRŽE UČITAVANJE STRANICE -->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 
 <!-- DODATNE SKRIPTE -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="_hsync_scripts/_hsync_registracija.js"></script> `

Isn't called? I debug it with `alert()` and it's work

Comment: I've updated your jsFiddle (added javascript, added the jquery which wasn't present there) and it just selects the random 'rasa' as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/petervanderwal/8ed5j97a/1/

Comment: I don't Know why for me don't work. I'm tired.. I'll keep same value before user change sex. It's easy :P
Btw. Thanks a lot for help! Have a great day :)